# can i simplify this code with conditional operator?

Tags: c#, operators

I want to get rid of that if else statement is their any way can i do it with the ternary operator/ conditional operators ?

```
public class control
{
public int result;
public int text;
}

public class someclas
{
 control con = new control();
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))  //// **Is it possible to use ternary / conditional operator to avoid below if else statements ?**
{
control.result = 123;
control.text = error;
}
else
{
control.text ="success";
}
}
```

Comment: You should be aware of how your code looks (indention, blank lines etc.). Code should be indented property (4 spaces, no tabs) to make the code more readable. Also a good idea to remove more than 2 consecutive blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
control con = String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? new control() { text = "success" } : 
                                            new control() { text = error, result = 123 };
```

Comment: In most cases, you should use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, not `== ""`, `== null`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No. That is not possible since there are multiple statements in the first block.

If you restructure your code, it is possible, but it doesn't help with readability.

Comment: what if the statements inside the block are different`if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(error){ count+=1;}else{result +="failed on something"}`

Comment: you have more code after if else to execute?? @user3629247

Comment: no - the ternary operator produces a single result.

Comment: @DanielA.White: didnt get u ? about restructuring the code

Comment: @user3629247 there is a way, but its not very clear - check out amanezjak's answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

u can simplify ur code like this:

```
var con = new control { text = "success" };
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) return;
con.result = 123;
con.text = error;
```

always try to remove unnecessary nested blocks. these blocks reduce code readability.